# Merging featureclasses with the same name in multiple geodatabases using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, error-000732

I tried merging all "Arc" feature class with same name nested in multiple geodatabases using ArcPy but didn't work

```
#importing module arcpy and os and glob
import arcpy, os, glob

#settin up an environment
#mainLoc = r'D:\NHP Project\2020_NHP work file\Toposheet\arcpy_practise\A02\HYDRO_LN'
#setting overwriteoutput as true
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
#defining the output locaiton
output_folder = r'D:\NHP Project\2020_NHP work file\Toposheet\rough_latest_output'

Dict = {}

myList = glob.glob(r'D:\NHP Project\2020_NHP work file\Toposheet\arcpy_practise\*\HYDRO_AR')
print myList
for value in myList:
    arcpy.env.workspace = value
    print(value)
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Arc"):
        if not fc in Dict:
            Dict[fc] = []
            #print(Dict[fc])
            Dict[fc].append(os.path.join(value, fc))
            #print(Dict[fc].append(os.path.join(value, fc)))
        else:
            Dict[fc].append(os.path.join(value, fc))


#loop through each key and merge them together
for key in Dict:
    output = os.path.join(output_folder, key[:-4]) + '_merge'
    arcpy.Merge_management(Dict[key], output)
    print output + " created"
```

As a result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "D:/NHP Project/2020_NHP work file/Toposheet/project_clip/arcpy_merge_topo.py", line 38, in <module>    
  arcpy.Merge_management(Dict[key], output)    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 4124, in Merge
    raise e  arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
    ERROR 000732: Input Datasets: 'D:\NHP Project\2020_NHP work file\Toposheet\OneDrive-2020-12-15\2785\D13\TRANS_LN\Arc' does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (Merge).
```

Comment: It appears you are trying to merge arcinfo coverage datasets. I've not used that format for many years so can't remember if that is a format that can be used by the merge tool? Try using the merge tool manually to confirm if a couple of coverage files actually merge? If not you will need to insert some export code before merging. Also your merge code is incorrect, you supply a LIST of input datasets to the merge tool, do not loop providing 1 at a time.

Comment: Thank you @Hornbydd for your valuable suggestion. I have tried merging the layers using ArcMap manually and it works. Also, I have merged the polygon feature using the same loop and it was successful. However, I am not sure why the IDE interprets the data as "not supported or does not exist". So if its possible can you please help me with the code??